# AngularUI Router: nested state not launching controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular and ui-router. I can't get a nested controller to launch, but if the state is not nested, the controller launches.

The URL is generated from the DnaNodeListCtrl template. The template generates what looks like a correct URL:
http://localhost:8080/#/v1/dnanodes/a9bfd497-ce6b-4832-909e-506a9b29e46e

My code is below. Why can't I launch a nested controller?

config.js:

```
var dnaMgrApp = angular.module('dnaMgrApp', [
     'ngRoute',
     'ui.router',
     'dnaMgrControllers',
     'dnaMgrRestService'
]);


dnaMgrApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('nodeList', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: 'templates/dnaNodeList.html',
            controller: 'DnaNodeListCtrl'
        })
        .state('nodeList.nodeDetail', {
            url: "v1/dnanodes/:nodeId",
            templateUrl: 'templates/dnaNodeSummary.html',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.title = 'My DNA';}
        });
});
```

Template:

```
<div id="body-container" >
    </div><div id="tablediv">
        <div  ng-repeat="node in dnaNodes">
            <div class="dnanode">
                <a ui-sref="nodeList.nodeDetail({nodeId:node.id})">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>{{node.geneName}}</td><td><img src="{{node.statusIcon}}"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2">2 DNA Pathways</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </a>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ui router works in such a way that the nested state needs to have the same url as the parent state + whatever you defined in your nested state.

As in:

if you have a state parent with url : `/foo`

Then you define a state nested with url: `/bar`

Then the resulting url you have to have to trigger the nested state is:

```
/foo/bar
```

Therefore, you need to add the / in your child url.

Edit
Just use that:

```
 .state('nodeList.nodeDetail', {
     url: "/v1/dnanodes/:nodeId",
     templateUrl: 'templates/dnaNodeSummary.html',
     //....
 });
```

Comment: The url is generated by ui-router in the parent template from code: ui-sref="nodeList.nodeDetail({nodeId:node.id})"

Adding the slash only changes a double slash added to the url: "http://localhost:8080/#//v1/dnanodes/27ae134e-1067-4788-a97d-0981deca2e53"

Comment: @garyM you misunderstood me, I meant just add a slash into the configuration for the child state.

Comment: Hi baba, I did place it in the child state which created the double slash and did not fix the problem. I also attempted in the fix in the template yielding the same double slash and again no solution. I'm puzzled over the reason..

Comment: can you provide a plunkr demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed..  The bottom line is the function is broken.. I posted on their google forum and there's been no response. I'm classifying ui-router as an unsupported, alpha library for now..

I'll try to revisit it in the next few days. I wish I knew where to trace through code stack to find the issue.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely supported, but we use this as our main support channel much more than Google Groups. Also, many people use it in production apps just fine. As mentioned above, if you'd like to post a link to a plunkr (which, if you're not allowed to do it, then you're doing it wrong -- a plunkr should be a minimum reproduction of the issue), then I'm sure someone here could debug it very quickly. You probably just messed up something simple.

Comment: @garyM I also wouldn't qualify ui-router as an 'unsuported-alpha' app as it is clearly superior than the $route service and as far as I know, its user base is bigger than any other $router-like interfaces, including $router itself.

Comment: @Nate: Thanks for replying.. as well as baba. It is appreciated

I'm new to both angular and ui-router. And the little I have experience with it, I absolutely love the approach. 

I do think there needs to be an architectural explanation of both to aid understanding specific to facilitate debugging of this and other core issues. 

I'll comeback to this in a few days as I'm up against a very tight deadline. 

Nate, yes agreed. I think what I'm doing wrong is something ridiculously simple.

I'm putting something together that I can release to the public.

Answer (score 0):

The parent template needs to have a place to render the child view. Specifically, the parent template needs to have at least `<ui-view/>`. This is explained in the [Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) guide.